# Xamarin.Forms XAML binding to x:String

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

Is there a way to dynamicaly assign Picker.Items from XAML?

Something like:

```
<Picker x:Name="pckTheme">
    <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>{Binding Option1Text}></x:String>
        <x:String>{DynamicResource Option2Text}></x:String>
    </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

(This sample is not working, of course).

As far as I can tell, the only allowed type in Picker.Items is x:String and I can't seem to find any method to bind to x:String.

Doing it from code is relatively simple, but I would prefer doing it from XAML directly, if possible.

Goal here is to localize content from resource file, but other uses may come handy.

Comment: What about binding the values ? doesn't that work for you?

Comment: That is what I am trying to do. It doesn't seem to be working for <x:String> .

Comment: I think you could read the information (your strings) from the resource files and inserted it into a list which is then bound to the Picker...

Comment: Thanks. That's the way I am doing it now. But then I also need to handle runtime language change from code, and that's why I wanted to do it from XAML.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would bind the `Picker` to a list of items which can be as dynamic as you want. To put them in there as hardcoded items isn't really dynamically assigning if you ask me. What you could do is create a `ValueConverter` to use in your XAML that gets the language specific value of a key and bind the `Picker` to a list of keys.

Comment: I am trying to get as much as I can from XAML. Idea is to use {Strings.keyValue} from Resources if I can, so localization would be handled by Xamarin.forms itself. So that is not hardcoding in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Please use the following XAML code:

```
<x:Array Type="{x:Type x:String}">
<x:Static Member="local:AppResources.Events"/>
<x:Static Member="local:AppResources.Device"/>
<x:Static Member="local:AppResources.Biographical"/>
</x:Array>
```

Where local is:

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:YOURNAMESPACE"
```

Answer (score 0):

`<x:string>` only supports constant values. You can address this issue with a [Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/markup-extensions/)

Its functionality is trivial: it returns its parameter.

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;

namespace YOURAPP.Extensions
{
    public class StringExtension : IMarkupExtension
    {
        public string Value { get; set; }

        public object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
        {
            return Value;
        }
    }
}
```

Use it like this in a view:

1. Add `xmlns:ext="clr-namespace:YOURAPP.Extensions"` to the root element
2. `<ext:StringExtension Value="{anything here}" />` where you would otherwise want `<x:string>`

Note that this causes an `Add` to be called to the `IEnumerable`. For the picker it works out of the box. For custom controls it requires initialization (to avoid a `NullReferenceException`) and and `ObservableCollection` to make sure that the view is updated on adding.